# Mobile HTML5 network detection and SMS sending

Tags: android, ios, html

I would like to create a mobile app that will detect network connectivity (e.g. 3G) and if no connectivity, then send out an SMS.

For Android and iOS, is this possible using HTML5?

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 2):

You can't programatically send an SMS on iOS, you can present an SMS compose view to the user and the user can decide whether they want to send it or not.

A pure HTML/web app on iOS cannot however access the ability to do this, but a hybrid app (i.e. one using UIWebView to load html instead of Safari) could.

Assuming this SMS behaviour is ok to you, then as you're going to have to create a hybrid app anyway, then it doesn't matter if iOS doesn't handle all the networking aspects of html5 as you could do that natively.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 has connectivity features. [Here is a demo](http://html5demos.com/offline) that catches online/offline events.

If you want more specific information on the network interface you'd have to proxy it from a native background task probably using a web socket.

Comment: But would this work for both iPhone and Android?  I checked the following url:http://mobilehtml5.org/ and under'Network Information API' it seems to indicate that only Android is supported.  Do you have more details around this?